# I am facing some issues related to expo ejection

Tags: expo, react-native, program-entry-point, unhandled-promise-rejection

When I run expo eject on an empty project created by create-react-native-app or my complete project created in the same way, I get the following error:

> Error: Group by name c:/Users/#folder-path#/ios/#projectname# not found!

The folder above does exist after the attempt. Here

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have never faced such type issue.but one way to solve this problem
1.Create new Project using react-native init firstapp
2.copy your code one by one into new react-native project from your expo project
3.every time run your project after paste first screen code.
Do not paste full code one by one..